# Call Task.Delay() and ask after few minutes how much time has left

Tags: c#, asynchronous, time, task, delay

I have a task for a simple delay of an hour (C#):

```
Task myTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
await myTask;
```

Is it possible to retrieve from the task how much time there is left for completion? and the catch is that I don't know when it begun. I just have a running Task.Delay in front of my eyes, that begun in the past.

For example: If 45 minutes have passed, I would like to get the answer: 15 minutes.

Comment: `var start = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: You will have to record the start time and calculate it yourself.

Comment: It is not possible with the built-in `Task` as is. Would you be OK with using a custom class, probably deriving from `Task`?

Answer (score 3):

No. All it exposes is a `Task`, and `Task` doesn't tell you *what* it's waiting for. It just tells you *when* it's done.

In the background, [`Task.Delay` uses a `Timer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5fb80297e082b8d6), but even the [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8) class won't tell you how much time is left.

You could make your own `Timer` class (you could even inherit from `Timer`) that exposes how much time is left.